# How to Get the h Block on Level 8 in Vim Adventure?

Tags: vim-adventures

I have been stuck at the following stage on level 8. Could anyone tell me how to get to the h block? I know I could get to the rest of blocks by the * key after it.

[image: screenshot1]

[image: keys]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure where your cursor is, so I'll start from the upper left corner, on the **H** in the "Here's an easy" line.  (Pressing `gg` from anywhere in the puzzle will take you there.)

- `$` to go to the end of line 1.
- `**` to go to the **e** in "That's not easy," near the bottom.
- `j` to go down to the **r** in **sir**, in the last line.
- `##` to go to the **s** in **sir**, in the "whose new socks, sir?" line, which I believe is the one where you're stuck.  (screenshot)
  [image: At the "s" in "sir".]
- Now, use `Fh` to backwards-find the **h** in **whose**.  (screenshot)
  [image: At the "h" in "whose".]
- The rest is probably obvious to you.  `*` or `#` to get to the **w** in **whose** in the "Who sews whose socks?" line, which will release a blue key.  `gg$*` to grab the key.  `*j*;*ekl` etc. to get to the building and use the blue key.
  [image: Get to the blue door building to grab the "n" key.]

I think that should explain everything pretty well.  Happy Vim Adventuring!

Comment: Thank you very much! I made it though! Appreciate your help!

Comment: Awesome :-)  If the answer was correct, please remember to mark it as "accepted".  And good luck with the rest of the game, one of my favs!